# Bootstrap 3: Alignment issues while creating form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having some alignment issues while creating a form using bootstrap 3.
I want to align my form towards left so that my form fields start from the left side. But with what I have is that there is lot of space on the left side of the form fields. I tried using "pull left" & margin css but it does not work.

Also another thing which I am not able to resolve is that it is somehow adding a scroll bar at the bottom of the screen, even though I dont have any data.

I have created a codepen for this at:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKNZwz

Not putting the entire code here as its a lot.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group pull-left" style="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Would appreciate inputs.

Comment: your horizontal scroll bar is only because of the negative margin you have on the class .form-horizontal .form-group

Comment: also you don't seem to have unnecessary space before the text box, the space you have is only the width of the 2-columns which has your text box label

Comment: @JismonThomas I don't see negative margin that I have added here. Also what is the appropriate solution for moving my form fields to left with the layout that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have negative margin on one of the classes, you have to remove that to avoid the horizontal scroll bar see the screenshot below
[image: look the margin left and right of -15px]

in order to reduce the space from left, you can make your label text to left align or make your label class `.col-sm-1`,

```
 .form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}

.form-horizontal .control-label {
  text-align: left;
}
```

I have added an updated pen, see if that helps you:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKBaYq